# SQLITE3: find IDs across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to do analysis of what codes appear in multiple tables under certains conditions. However I don't think the database schema suits the task very well but maybe there's something I don't know about that can help me. Here's a simplified schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "batchDescription" (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "simulationDetails" (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ko_index_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        batch_description_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        data1 REAL NOT NULL,
        data2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
        FOREIGN KEY(ko_index_id) REFERENCES "koIndex" (id)
        FOREIGN KEY(batch_description_id) REFERENCES "batchDescription" (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "koIndex" (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        number_of_kos INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "1kos" (
        ko_index_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ko1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ko_index_id)
        FOREIGN KEY(ko_index_id) REFERENCES "koIndex" (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "2kos" (
        ko_index_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ko1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ko2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ko_index_id)
        FOREIGN KEY(ko_index_id) REFERENCES "koIndex" (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "3kos" (
        ko_index_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ko1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ko2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ko3 INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ko_index_id)
        FOREIGN KEY(ko_index_id) REFERENCES "koIndex" (id)
);
```

This goes up to table "525kos" which has ko1 to ko525 in it - ko1 to ko525 are IDs that are primary keys in a table not shown here. I want to do an analysis of how often certain IDs are present under certain conditions. Here is a simple example to illustrate:

I would like to like to count the amount of times a certain ID (let's say 127) (in any koX column) in the "13kos" table occurs when simulationDetails.data1 not equal to 0. I would do this on a database called ko.db from the bash command line like:

```
for ko_idx in {1..13}; do sqlite3 ko.db "select count(ko${ko_idx}) from '13kos' where ko${ko_idx} = 127 and ko_index_id in (select ko_index_id from simulationDetails where data1 != 0);"; done
```

Already this is slow and inefficient but is simple compared to what I would like to do. What if I wanted to do an analysis of all the IDs in all possible columns in all "Xkos" tables and compare them to where data1 is equal and not equal to zero?

Can anybody direct me to a better way of doing this or is the schema design just not very good for this kind of analysis and I'll have to give up?

EDIT: Thought I'd add a bit of extra detailto avoid confusion. I suspect that a good way to achieve want I want would be to somehow combine all the "Xkos" tables into one temporary table and then search for certain IDs from that table. How would I combine all 525 ko tables without writing out each table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I combine all 525 ko tables without writing out each table
>   name?

1. Create a table with the same number of columns as the largest table (the table into which you merge) allowing nulls.
2. query the **sqlite_master** table using something like :-

   `SELECT * from sqlite_master WHERE name LIKE '%kos%' AND type = 'table'`
3. Loop through the extracted table names building an `INSERT SELECT` for each table that will insert the rows from the tables into the table created in 1.

   - See [2. INSERT INTO table SELECT ...;](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)  especially in regard to handling missing columns.
4. All done, the table created in 1 will be populated accordingly.